# What does a function without body mean?

Tags: go, abstract-methods

I'm reading the code that package `time`, and then I want to know how the `func After(d Duration) <-chan Time` works.

I found the code follows:

```
func After(d Duration) <-chan Time {
    return NewTimer(d).C
}

func NewTimer(d Duration) *Timer {
    c := make(chan Time, 1)
    t := &Timer{
        C: c,
        r: runtimeTimer{
            when: nano() + int64(d),
            f:    sendTime,
            arg:  c,
        },
    }
    startTimer(&t.r)
    return t
}
```

So I found the definition of `startTimer` - it's so weird that function `startTimer` does not  have a function body.

```
func startTimer(*runtimeTimer)
```

I want to know that :

1. Where is the real code of `startTimer`
2. Why an "abstract method" can exists here
3. Why the author of Go wrote it like this

Thanks!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

1. The function is defined [here](https://golang.org/src/runtime/time.go#L206):

   ```golang
   // startTimer adds t to the timer heap.
   //go:linkname startTimer time.startTimer
   func startTimer(t *timer) {
       if raceenabled {
           racerelease(unsafe.Pointer(t))
       }
       addtimer(t)
   }
   ```
2. [Function declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations):

   > A function declaration may omit the body. Such a declaration provides the signature for a function implemented outside Go, such as an assembly routine.
3. Not every programming language can express its own runtime entirely (C can, for example). Parts of the Go runtime and the standard library are in C, parts are in assembly while some other are in `.goc`, which is a not well documented hybrid of Go and C.

Comment: @CheneyEah, see [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/134e72302b9a3441/d44169a540437357) for more info on `.goc` files.

Comment: Side note: as with Go, there are bits of the C runtime that are best written in some other language (usually assembly). It may be *possible* to write, e.g., ldexp and frexp in (non-portable) C but it's usually easier to get it right in assembly.