# Where is time.Sleep function declaration?

Tags: go

Here are the first lines of the file [`sleep.go`](https://golang.org/src/time/sleep.go?s=308:330#L1) in the `time` package of the Go core library:

```
// Sleep pauses the current goroutine for at least the duration d.
// A negative or zero duration causes Sleep to return immediately.

func Sleep(d Duration)

// runtimeNano returns the current value of the runtime clock in nanoseconds.
func runtimeNano() int64
```

Why is there no declaration of the function `time.Sleep` here? Where is it?

Comment: I've found this: [What does a function without body mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938960/what-does-a-function-without-body-mean), which might help you...

Answer (score 4):

It's in [runtime/time.go](https://golang.org/src/runtime/time.go#L47).

See the [compiler directives](https://golang.org/cmd/compile/#hdr-Compiler_Directives) for details on `go:linkname`.