# Where is math.Max defined?

Tags: function, go, math

I was reading the source code of package [**math**](https://golang.org/src/math/dim.go) and I don't understand how the `Max` function is defined.

Namely, there seems to be a function definition for `Max` that somehow *hangs*, for lack of a better word.

Also, there seems to be another non-exported function named `max` with the same signature as `Max`, but this time, its implementation is present.

Why doesn't the compiler complain about function `Max` in eg

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Max(1.1, 2.2)=", math.Max(1.1, 2.2))
}
```

whereas if one does something like

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func A() bool

func a() bool { return true }

func main() {
    fmt.Println(A())
}
```

in the [*Playground*](https://play.golang.org/p/2ZBYuRCLM5U), the compiler produces`./prog.go:7:6: missing function body`?

How is it possible to call `math.Max` and obtain a result, when the body of the function, in its source file, is missing?

### Edit

I think it's not a duplicate of the cited questions because this question is predominantly interested about `math.Max` and its implementation and only circumstantially touches upon the issue addresed in the linked questions which is function definitions without a body. Also, it might prove useful to a future search about `Max` to  read the comments about the implementation of `Max` in assembly outside of Go.

Comment: There seem to be platform specific implementations for those functions, in assembly: https://golang.org/src/math/dim_amd64.s . Also relevant: https://golang.org/doc/asm

Comment: @FelixKling how come the compiler doesn't complain about the `Max` function missing its body? Or is it the case that the source file containing its signature is a mock-up file for display purposes only?

Comment: I guss this will answer your question: [What does a function without body mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14938960/218196). Maybe even a duplicate?

Comment: @FelixKling practically, yes; but I think there is no answer there for the location of the implementation of `Max` that you provided in your comment above so I guess if someone in the future is interested about that, they might find your comment to my question useful...

Comment: If you're asking because you want to know what the behavior of the Max function is, look at the lowercase max function, as that is the default and all platform specific implementations are supposed to be compliant with it.  If you want to see the assembly implementations for different platforms, you can search within the math package source files.  This file contains the amd64 source https://github.com/golang/go/blob/0e85fd7561de869add933801c531bf25dee9561c/src/math/dim_amd64.s